# How do I get my browser to default to a larger font?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, fonts

I have a wide screen laptop, and I've noticed that when I'm viewing websites, the website font is really small and I end up just having two white strips on either side of my page.

I have to essential press Ctrl +, which will enlarge the page to take advantage of the white space and make the font bigger.

However, I seem to have to do it on every page. Is there some sort of way I can just have it as default.

I use Chrome and Firefox

Answer (score 7):

**On Windows**

*In Chrome* go to **Options > Under the Bonnet/Hood > Change font and language settings**

[image: Under the bonnet]

and pick the new font size you want for each font type. The **Change...** button brings up the standards Windows font chooser dialog.

[image: Pick a font]

*In Firefox* go to **Tools > Options > Content**

Here you can set the size of the font independently of the font face (1):

[image: Content Options]

Selecting **Advanced...** (2) brings up a similar dialog to Chrome's but again you can set the size independently:

[image: Any font]

Comment: I've just double checked IE for completeness and found that while you can change the font face you can't change the font size.

Answer (score 1):

For Firefox you should get [NoSquint](http://urandom.ca/nosquint/).  It's a remarkable add-on!  It lets you:

- Override the default text-only and full-page (both text and images) zoom levels for all websites
- Enforce your own foreground and background colors
- Remember your zoom levels and color settings per site, automatically applying them when you return.

Answer (score 1):

The [AutoZoom](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/ocdkpkoaonnchdakgkmmcmnihhhgbjch) extension for Google Chrome can do this for you.

Answer (score 1):

On the version of Firefox (3.6.10) I have on my Linux box at work, I can set the default font size via Edit -> Preferences -> Content.  Then click the up and down on the Size field to set the font to the size you want.

[image]